# Are private US universities just a OPT mill, without much concern to teaching quality?

Tags: academic-life, motivation

I started a Master in Engineering Management in Santa Clara University, a quite respected university in the Silicon Valley, in order to have a degree better recognized in the US as I've just studied in Brazil and France so far. I've run in a few issues to adapt to the US academic reality that are making me rethink if that was a good decision. Although the pandemic has affected some of the academics, it doesn't seem to be be much of the issue here. Here are some issues I've run into:

- Professors don't have much knowledge out of the scope of their classes. One day I asked a professor about alternative tools to the one he was teaching us and he said he haven't heard of any, despite a quick Google search showing several that I quickly tried to check that indeed they were alternatives. This shocked me as usually my professors in Brazil would be PhDs in the subjects that they were teaching undergrads and were constantly publishing papers with a very advanced knowledge of the skill they were introducing us to. So if a student wants to follow that field, they can just contact the professor that taught the introductory course.
- Grading appears to be more based on clerical work of delivering homework and finals with very little of the subject's knowledge are more about working on it. My projects, midterms and finals as an undergrad student in Brazil were much more detailed and expected the student to have a very high skill on it to earn good grades. The clerical work on writing the papers was the least of the efforts for each course. This leaves the courses of quite bland academic taste.
- While I don't hear much, I noticed that vast majority of students appear to be international students coming to graduate and get their OPT, so they can immigrate to the US. I don't see that vibe of genius students that I would expect in a respected university in an area with high demand for skilled workers. It feels more those private colleges in Brazil that people go just because they can't go to a good university so they just study enough to graduate and get a certificate.
- There is next to no activities outside the academic field I'm pursing the degree for. My university in Brazil would demand us to earn credits from at least three extra-curricular activities while at SCU the only credited (and even there optional) extra curricular activity is internship. In France we were expected to learn at least two foreign languages, do a few 'human development' courses, like arts or sports and have plenty of off-curriculum courses, like marketing, law or management, despite being an engineering school. I don't see any of that here at SCU.

I'm thinking that maybe I should transfer for a university of the UC system, where possibly there would be a more academic vibe than a OPT-driven vibe, just to provide students with the documents to allow them to work and immigrate to the US.

Me question here is, is it because private universities are there just to give students an advance STEM certificate that I'm getting bored and unable to motivate to study? Should I move to an university more academically renowned so that I could relate more and be more motivated to conclude my degree?

Comment: The top private universities in the US, such as MIT, Stanford, Caltech, Princeton and so on are not really OPT mills. Down the ladder a little bit though, it's harder to answer and possibly depends on other factors. Your particular experience could well be due to the proximity of your university to Silicon Valley.

Comment: Can you clarify  the abbreviation OPT mill for a multi-national audience of readers? [edit]

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩, probably this: https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/optional-practical-training-opt-for-f-1-students

Comment: @Brian OPT mills are universities with the sole or mostly purpose to provide the paperwork for students without the right to work on US soil to work legally in the US for a limited time, typically one year to three years. The students typically use this as a mean to get the foot in the door in tech companies to have them provide the paperwork to immigrate to the US.

Comment: @GabrielDiego Please [edit] your question to be stand-alone without your comment, as comments are ephemeral. Thanks :-)

Comment: For point 4, I would refer you to the difference between undergrad degrees and professional masters degrees in the US. Breadth requirements are a characteristic of the former, almost never the latter.

Comment: @Dawn, not necessarily. In France, were I did my exchange, Master students were also required to have extra curricular activities or just offered some. And for a Master in Engineering Management in the Silicon Valley, knowing some foreign languages is really essential.

Answer (score 5):

That is an awfully broad brush to use to try to paint more than a thousand institutions.

Most private colleges and universities in the US are *primarily* undergraduate institutions, though many have a small graduate division. A small number are renowned research institutions as pointed out in a comment. But most are not. Instead, their mission is to provide a good "well rounded" broad undergraduate education that enables graduates to move into a wide range of careers after graduation, including, but not exclusive to, academia. Many graduates move on to graduate school and many professors (myself) encourage graduates to go elsewhere for their grad degrees even if the school has a corresponding graduate division.

But, you may well be better off at a state sponsored institution, since nearly all of them (and all the higher ranked ones) stress research. However, they may or may not put heavy emphasis on masters level education.

But, I doubt that there are any (not-for-profit, accredited) schools in the US that have a specific goal of being an "OPT mill". I'd be surprised to learn of one.

Note that the quality of private schools can vary quite a bit, though accreditation by the traditional organizations tries to limit the range. But not every small school can provide deep specialization in *all* fields.

---

Disclosure: I have family members that attended SCU and all are happy with it and have encouraged their children to also go there. But that is for the undergraduate program and the general academic environment.

Many, perhaps hundreds of thousands or more, successful academics and high level professionals started out at such institutions.

Note that my interpretation of "private" includes only not-for-profit accredited colleges and universities of which the US has over a thousand.

Comment: Thanks for your through response, but it doesn't address some issues, like lack of interest of faculty and students on their subjects and lack of out-of-scope activities. I followed recommendations of friends and online reviews to join SCU and they indeed reported a mucb greater quality in the past, but the current situation doesn't reflect their fame. I don't think this is explained by the pandemic

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you enrol in a Masters in Engineering Management, you can expect to find both the university and the students are only there to get some money.  That's what the program is for.

That is not necessarily indicative of the broader environment of the university or the nation.

An "OPT Mill" would not have any classes at all.

Comment: There are Zoom meetings, but content is often not delivered, that's why I would feel like they are just milling units to mill an OPT in the end.